# Вывести записи с поля input в других input js

Tags: javascript

Есть поле input

```
<input type="text"onkeyup="document.getElementById('quantity_order_days').value = this.value"/>
```

где будет выводиться информация в других input

```
<input type="number" id="quantity_order_days">
<input type="number" id="quantity_order_days">
<input type="number" id="quantity_order_days">
```

Выводиться только в первом, можно так сделать что бы выводился во всех ?

Comment: Средствами javascript вроде нужно получить элементы а потом перебирая через forEach задать им value, и вообще не нужно дублировать элементы с одинаковыми id на странице, используйте в этом случае класс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вы ищите елемент по ИД, предполагаеться что такой елемент только 1н, и естественно находиться первый, куда значение и проставляеться, как и написано в комментарии нужно найти все инпуты и циклом им проставить нужное значение, например так :

```js
const fn = (that) => {
  [...document.getElementsByClassName('quantity_order_days')].forEach(e => e.value = that.value)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="fn(this)" />

<input type="number" class="quantity_order_days">
<input type="number" class="quantity_order_days">
<input type="number" class="quantity_order_days">
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы не правильно используете `id` элемента, `id` должен быть всегда уникальным поэтому он так и называется, а у Вас он на 3-х элементах! , для похожих элементов используются классы 'class'. Для решения задачи код ниже:

```js
var inputKeyUp = document.getElementById('keyup-input');
var inputQuantity = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity_order_days');
inputKeyUp.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  Array.from(inputQuantity).map(function(item) {
    item.value = parseInt(e.target.value);
  });
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="keyup-input" />
<br>
Результат: <br>
<div class="container">
  <input type="number" class="quantity_order_days">
  <input type="number" class="quantity_order_days">
  <input type="number" class="quantity_order_days">
</div>
```